# Test ipad 2 camera with xcode simulator  IOS 5

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am testing ipad camera application with ipad simulator 
I used below code, change the source type instead of camera.

```
  -(IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender{


    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]){

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = 
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate =(id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>) self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    [imagePicker release];
    newMedia = YES;

    }
```

}

When it run in the simulator error came up in ios 5 simulator .

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'On iPad,     UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'
```

But its working on 4.3 simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with iOS5 you need to show the pickercontroller in a popover view rather than a modal view.

From the apple documentation: On iPad, present the user interface using a popover. Doing so is valid only if the sourceType property of the image picker controller is set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. To use a popover controller, use the methods described in “Presenting and Dismissing the Popover” in UIPopoverController Class Reference.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Here is an example of presenting a UIImagePickerController inside a popover view:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                     inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                     animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks,There is a warning at line 2. Is it ok if i use                                              imagePicker.delegate = (id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>)self;